# Relating a point to the shifted axes.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

In the figure below, point ***O*** is the origin with lines marked with yellow, point ***O'*** is the shifted origin with lines marked with white color. The point  ***(P,Q)*** is at a distance ***PO*** from the ***v*** axis and ***QO*** form the normal (green line) to the ***v*** axis. With regards to ***O'***, point ***(P,Q)*** is at a distance ***PO'*** from ***v'*** and ***QO'*** from ***u'***. Point ***O*** is shifted to ***O'*** by ***x*** and ***y*** distance (along the horizontal and vertical of the picture). The angle between ***u'*** and the line normal to ***v*** is **$\theta$**.

[image]

How to relate the point ***(P,Q)*** with ***O***, ***O'***, angle **$\theta$**, and the shifts ***x*** and ***y***?

Comment: Just gonna ask, but are the axis $u'$ and $v'$ perpendicular?
Also your question is unclear, "relate" doesn't mean much by itself... I guess you want to express the coordinates $PO$ and $QO$ with respect to $PO'$ and $QO'$ using the parameters $\theta$, $x$ and $y$... ?

Comment: Then the standard, simple way to do that, is to write the coordinate change for only a rotation, and then for only a translation, then to combine the two.

Comment: @N.Bach yes, axis $u′$ and $v′$ are perpendicular and yes I am trying to express the coordinates $PO$ and $QO$ with respect to $PO′$ and $QO′$ using the parameters $θ$, $x$ and $y$ but, $PO$, $QO$, $PO′$ and $QO′$ are known measured quantities while, $θ$, $x$ and $y$ are unknowns.

Comment: Regardless of who is known/unknown, the relationship between those quantities is still the same. What may change, is that it may be more annoying to compute $x$, $y$ and $\theta$ from those equations.

Comment: I reread more carefully, but you're missing some information in your problem. The translation/shift parameters $x,y$ are disconnected from your other coordinates system. Assuming that axis $u$ is horizontal, you need the angle between axis $u$ and some other axis or it's impossible to solve.

Comment: @N.Bach Ok, if I say we can measure the angle between $u$ and $v$, then?

Comment: Then it's possible... if I have some time I'll post a proper answer in a few hours.

Comment: After writing it down, I realized you can deduce that angle from $PO$ and $QO$... I admit, your notations are confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until I have time to write a more detailed answer, you can still look through this page on wikipedia: [rotation of axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes).

### Edit

I'm going to make a pretty important assumption in the following, which is that everything has an algebraic value and not a geometric one.
To put that into perspective, and in case I made a bad translation from my mother tongue, algebraic distances may have negative values whereas geometric distances are always non-negative. In a nutshell, geometric = $\lvert$algebraic$\rvert$.
As is, in your figure, $y<0$ (according to my notations). So you'll have to adapt depending on what you actually have.

**Notations**
There are three coordinates systems naturally attached to your problem:

- $uO\bar u$, where $O\bar u$ denotes the axis orthogonal to $Ou$ (and $uO\bar u$ is a right-handed). This is the natural system to express the shift from $O$ to $O'$ (the values of $x$ and $y$).
- $vO\bar v$, same as above but with axis $Ov$. In this system, the point you called "$(P,Q)$" has abscissae $QO$ and ordinate $PO$.
- $v'O'\bar{v'}$, same logic as above but the origin is $O'$. In a sense "$\bar{v'}=-u'$" (if this even makes sense). I'll still favour the notation
  $\bar{v'}$ because right-handed coordinates system are more natural for me ($v'O'u'$ is left-handed if I interpret the figure properly).
  In this system, point $(P,Q)$ has abscissae $QO'$ and ordinate $PO'$.

Denote by $\varphi$ the oriented angle between the axes $Ou$ and $Ov$.
Likewise $\theta$ is the oriented angle between axes $Ov$ and $Ov'$.
We're going to express everything in the coordinates system $vO\bar v$.

**Working the relations between the various coordinates**
First up is the vector $OO'$ which has coordinates $(x,y)$ in $uO\bar u$.
this same vector has coordinates $(X,Y)$ in $vO\bar v$ where
\begin{align*}
X&=x\cos\varphi +y\sin\varphi\\
Y&=-x\sin\varphi +y\cos\varphi
\end{align*}

Next, consider the auxiliary coordinate system $v''O'\bar{v''}$ with origin $O'$ and exactly the same orientation as $vO\bar{v}$; in other words the oriented angle between axes $Ov''$ and $Ov$ is $-\theta$. To go from system $v'O'\bar{v'}$ to system $vO\bar v$, you can first go from $v'O'\bar{v'}$ to
$v''O'\bar{v''}$ with a simple rotation of angle $-\theta$, then go from $v''O'\bar{v''}$ to $vO\bar v$ with a translation of vector $-OO'$.
Assume you have some point with coordinates
$(a,b)$ in $vO\bar v$,
$(a',b')$ in $v'O'\bar{v'}$,
and
$(a'',b'')$ in $v''O'\bar{v''}$. Then
\begin{align}
a'' &=& a'\cos(-\theta) + b'\sin(-\theta) &=& a'\cos\theta -b'\sin\theta \\
b'' &=& -a'\sin(-\theta) + b'\cos(-\theta) &=& a'\sin\theta +b'\cos\theta \\
a'' &=& a-X\\
b'' &=& b-Y
\end{align}

Putting everything together
\begin{align*}
a-x\cos\varphi-y\sin\varphi &= a'\cos\theta -b'\sin\theta \\
b+x\sin\varphi-y\cos\varphi &= a'\sin\theta +b'\cos\theta
\end{align*}
In particular for your point "$(P,Q)$"
\begin{align*}
QO-x\cos\varphi-y\sin\varphi &= QO'\cos\theta -PO'\sin\theta &(1)\\
PO+x\sin\varphi-y\cos\varphi &= QO'\sin\theta +PO'\cos\theta &(2)
\end{align*}

**Figuring out $x$, $y$ and $\theta$?**
From your answer to my comment it seems that you want some way to compute/figure out $x$, $y$ and $\theta$ given the measurements of $PO$, $PO'$, $QO$, $QO'$ and maybe $\varphi$. This is impossible as is. Although the equations are not linear with respect to $\theta$, you only have $2$ equations for $3$ unknowns, and in this particular case you have an infinity of possible values for $x$, $y$ and $\theta$. You need the measurements for another point to get unique values for those parameters. There is however a "nice" relationship 
between $x$, $y$ and $\theta$.

Notice that $O'$ lies on the circle centered at $(P,Q)$ with radius the distance between $O'$ and $(P,Q)$ (this can be proved from equations $(1)$ and $(2)$):
$$
(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = (d')^2
$$
where
$(d')^2=(PO')^2+(QO')^2$, and
$x_0=QO\cos\varphi -PO\sin\varphi$,
$y_0=QO\sin\varphi +PO\cos\varphi$ are the coordinates of 
$(P,Q)$ in $uO\bar u$.
[Note that $y_0$ should be null.]
The possible values of $(x,y)$ are such that there exists some real number $t$, $x=x_0+d'\cos t$ and $y=y_0+d'\sin t$.

Let $\psi$ such that $\cos\psi=\frac{QO'}{d'}$ and $\sin\psi=\frac{PO'}{d'}$.
If you re-inject the values $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ into equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ 
you eventually find (after an annoying development) that
$\theta+\varphi+\psi = t+\pi$ (if you use radians), or
$\theta+\varphi+\psi = t+180$ (with °).

So to sum this up, the possible triplets are
$
\left\{
\Big( x(t),\ y(t),\ \theta(t) \Big)
\mid t\in\mathbb R
\right\}
$
where
\begin{align*}
x(t) &= x_0 +d'\cos t \\
y(t) &= y_0 +d'\sin t \\
\theta(t) &= t+180-\varphi-\psi
\end{align*}

### Edit 2

Corrected abscissae and ordinate in the above
Also note that you have
$\cos\varphi = -\frac{QO}{d}$ and
$\sin\varphi = \frac{PO}{d}$, where
$d^2=QO^2+PO^2$. So you technically don't have to measure $\varphi$ if you already have $PO$ and $QO$. This also implies that $y_0=0$ and $x_0=-d$.

Also noticed I messed up part of my development for $\theta(t)$ so here are a little more details. When you check out $QO\times(1)+PO\times(2)$ you end up with
$$
d'd\cos t = -d'd\cos(\varphi+\psi+\theta)
$$
whereas $PO\times(1)-QO\times(2)$ gives
$$
-d'd\sin t = d'd\sin(\varphi+\psi+\theta)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried simulating the values and used the equations you presented but, I don't seem to get the results near the simulated values. Here you can find the simulated image https://i.stack.imgur.com/tus8b.jpg    . The $PO$ and $PO'$ measurements are absolute values (ignoring the minus, if the quadrants are considered).

Comment: @radk That's because I mixed up the abscissae and ordinate, I'll edit it.

Comment: Also, I am using Matlab to solve the systems of equations, so could you state all the equations together that should be used?

Comment: @radk From your figure, you can use nearly everything as is, except $y\approx -6.228$. Also in this configuration you have $\psi\approx 48.327°$.
If you plug in $t=-5.571°$ into my last few equations you'll retrieve the values of $x$, $y$ and $\theta$.
And no I can't tell you what equations to use since I still don't know what you're trying to do. Solving for $x$, $y$ and $\theta$ is impossible with only the data given, you need more sample points. Not to mention I don't use matlab so I can't help you much on the programming aspect.

Comment: I guess then if that another sample point is $t$ then the last three equations will work.

Comment: @radk That's a strange thing to say, because $t$ is a parameter, you can't exactly sample it. More context would help me answer your questions better btw.
Anyway, using your notations, let's say you have another point $(R,S)$ and the measurements $RO$, $SO$, $RO'$, $SO'$. Then there would exist a real $u\in\mathbb R$ and 3 new equations in $u$ such that $x=x(u)$, $y=y(u)$ and $\theta=\theta(u)$. You can then equate them to $x=x(t)$, etc., and obtain 3 equations with 2 unknowns that can easily be solved with some trigonometry.

Comment: @radk oh, while I'm at it, for that other point you actually need it's angle "$\varphi$"? I doubt $(R,S)$ would be on axis $Ou$ so the relationship between $RO$, $SO$ and the angle would not hold. Actually I have no clue what the situation is supposed to be, so I have no clue what part of my equations would still hold for a new "sample point". This is why including context is usually good.

Comment: This is more a physical problem, that's why I am still trying to figure out what I could measure and what I would treat as a parameter. Think of the yellow lines as an image with axis $uO$ and $O\bar{u}$ while the lines $v'$ and $u'$ as axis of the frame.  I am trying to find the rotation and translation of the point (including axes) $O$ wrt $O'$.

Comment: And also then I can sample the angle $t$ using information:  $uO$, $(P,Q)$, $O'$ and $v'$

Comment: @radk Image? I don't get why axis $Ov$ is skewed, is it the result of projecting from 3D to 2D? Because if this is related to camera models, I'm pretty sure there's a bunch of literature on the problem (I've never read it though)... Also if you want to map one set of axes onto the other, only using rotations and translations won't cut it, those things preserve angles, which is obviously not the situation you have since $Ov$ and $Ou$ do not form a right angle.

Comment: yes, it's one of computer graphics 3D to 2D projection problems, nevermind. Your answer has helped me to understand the issue in my physical problem.